# Could Django-channels co-exists with celery

Tags: django, celery, channel

If I make up a site with Django-channels(nginx + channels, I like its websocket  ability), Could I still adding in some celery app/tasks run at background as other normal django project?

Comment: Sure, why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Thank. I thought Django-channel uses another wsgi server, then Celery may not compacted with.

Comment: Channels uses asgi instead of wsgi, but celery is a standalone process, it doesn't care which server you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, you can use both.

For example https://vincenttide.com/blog/1/django-channels-and-celery-example/

- In browser side

You create websocket, server send real-time message.

https://github.com/VincentTide/django-channels-celery-example/blob/6ddc5ace0e1b99031ad0505ba0ec20be3f87704d/templates/jobs/index.html#L73

- In consumer side

You receive request, create task (and tell which channel to reply).

```
@channel_session
def ws_receive(message):
    job.delay(message.reply_channel.name)
```

- In celery worker

You receive task, run it. and send real-time message to browser via daphne.

```
@app.task
def job(reply_channel):
    Channel(reply_channel).send({
        "text": json.dumps ({
            "action": "completed",
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

The **answer is** **Yes**. Celery is a different standalone process. And you can use django-channels and celery like you would use celery with Django.